# Oops, looks like this request tried to create an infinite loop

Tags: drupal

Every time I use a redirect from an URL alias i receive the foloowing report of:

Oops, looks like this request tried to create an infinite loop. We do not allow such things here. We are a professional website!

Ive tried clearing all the cache and ran cron.

I've tried searching everywhere and can't seem to fix it. Thank you kindly for your support.

Comment: Without providing very precise details, no one would be able to help you. You need to mention the site, if live, the URL which you are facing issue with and what you learned from the Drupal/apache logs.

Comment: Probably you have a page or a node on that specific URL you want to add your alias.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be you have an issue with your Redirect module.

If you edit a node you will see that it somehow creates a redirect which is the same as the pages existing URL alias.
Seems to be related to [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1796596#comment-6549638) post.

Try to delete redirections and clear the cache again.